# Reuse code inside if statement. (Is function inside function bad practice?)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, reusability

I heard from some tutorials that defining functions inside function is bad practice.

In my case I need to reuse some code inside two nested callbacks. For example:

```
router.get('...', function(req, res) {
  db.on('load', function(){
    function doRequest() {
      // Valid token required to do the request.
    }

    if (!validToken) {
      getValidToken().then(... doRequest() ...)
    }
    else {
      doRequest()
    }
  });
});
```

You see the function `doRequest()` is defined inside other functions (callbacks). Someday in the future I may need to do something like this, but inside `defined` by me `function`. Is that wrong?

Do I using bad practice in this "code"? Can I make it better?

Comment: This is my opinion, but I think a function defined in a function is a perfectly ok thing to do. If that code isn't reusable and is tailored only for this situation then I think it's better to write it within the function than expose it... plus writing it somewhere else just separates it from where the action is happening making it hard to tell in an eyeshot what this code is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `doRequest()` is defined inside the scope of the callback, it will only exist on that scope. It's called a closure and it's useful in many situations. So if you only use this function inside this scope, it's not a problem, as you won't be duplicating content.

On the other hand, if `doRequest()` performs generic functions and does not access data from the callback (without being sent as a parameter), it should be defined outside, so that it can later be reused.

In the end, it's really a matter of balancing code maintenability, performance and data access. Here's a tutorial on [scopes and closures](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/).